# Material UI - Tabs: Scrollbar moves late. Even though the tab is rendered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I am using tabs

```
<Tabs
  value={valueTab}
  onChange={handleChange}
  textColor="secondary"
  indicatorColor="secondary"
>
  <Tab label="Incoming" />
  <Tab label="Outgoing" />
</Tabs>
```

We can see the scroll bar is not moving immediately to Outgoing.

[image]

I Can see the outgoing page loaded. Only a small table in it is fetching some data inside useEffect.

I dont want the scrollbar to wait till the entire component is loaded.

I can see the outgoing Component but the scrollbar is stuck at Incoming.

How to make scroll bar not worry the useEffect completed in the Outgoing component

[image]